# Visual Studio - change the publish location per solution configuration

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, configuration

In Visual Studio, how can I change the publish location depending on solution  configuration (Release/Debug/etc...)?

The box is grayed out in the Publish tab, not sure no one at Microsoft thought of this,

[image: settings window]

I need two release channels - beta and canary (more beta), both are built as a subtypes of the original Release target, and I switch between them using the dropdown:

[image: target dropdown]

Comment: I don't have vs15 right now in front of me but in vs12 i can do it. Also, vs15 had config json file where you can specify all sorts of things. I am sure, you can also add conditional publish to proj file. Just copy publish section modify so you have 2 or more different sections, and add condition to each of those to run specific section for specific configuration.